# MPI custom handler for NULL communicator errors specifically

Tags: c, error-handling, callback, mpi

**Is it possible to customize the error function handlers for error having to do with invalid communicators (typically NULL communicator)?**

It seems that I <s>can</s> can't even associate an error handler to the NULL communicator with the call `MPI_Comm_set_errhandler( MPI_COMM_NULL, newerr );`

The example is too simple and MPI_COMM_NULL is hardcode but the idea is that sometimes the communicator can be NULL at runtime as the result.

So, it there an error handler at the global library level to catch error with the NULL communicator?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
static int calls = 0;
static int errs = 0;
static MPI_Comm mycomm;

void eh( MPI_Comm *comm, int *err, ... )
{
    printf( "eh called\n" );fflush(stdout);
    if (*err != MPI_ERR_OTHER) {
        errs++;
        printf( "Unexpected error code\n" );fflush(stdout);
    }
    if (*comm != mycomm) {
        errs++;
        printf( "Unexpected communicator\n" );fflush(stdout);
    }
    calls++;
    return;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    MPI_Comm comm;
    MPI_Errhandler newerr;

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    comm = MPI_COMM_NULL;//MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    mycomm = comm;
    MPI_Comm_create_errhandler( eh, &newerr );
    int s = MPI_Comm_set_errhandler( comm, newerr ); // Gives fatal error
    assert(s == MPI_SUCCESS);
    int rank = -1;
    MPI_Comm_rank( comm, &rank );
    MPI_Comm_call_errhandler( comm, MPI_ERR_OTHER );
    MPI_Errhandler_free( &newerr );
    if (calls != 1) {
        errs++;
        printf( "Error handler not called\n" );fflush(stdout);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using both `MPICH` and `OpenMPI`, with the same result.

---

I checked the implementation of MPICH, the point where the invalid/null communicator is checked in in the file `include/mpiimpl.h` (for example called from `int MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_Comm comm, int *rank )`)

I don't see immediately an a customization point that will allow to capture this error.

```
/* Check not only for a null pointer but for an invalid communicator,
   such as one that has been freed.  Let's try the ref_count as the test
   for now */
/* ticket #1441: check (refcount<=0) to cover the case of 0, an "over-free" of
 * -1 or similar, and the 0xecec... case when --enable-g=mem is used */
#define MPID_Comm_valid_ptr(ptr,err,ignore_rev) {     \
     MPID_Valid_ptr_class(Comm,ptr,MPI_ERR_COMM,err); \
     if ((ptr) && MPIU_Object_get_ref(ptr) <= 0) {    \
         MPIR_ERR_SET(err,MPI_ERR_COMM,"**comm");     \
         ptr = 0;                                     \
     } else if ((ptr) && (ptr)->revoked && !(ignore_rev)) {        \
         MPIR_ERR_SET(err,MPIX_ERR_REVOKED,"**comm"); \
     }                                                \
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to customize the error function handlers for error having to do with invalid communicators (typically NULL communicator)?

No, you can't. It is explicitly stated by documentation:

[MPI_Comm_set_errhandler](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Comm_set_errhandler.html)

> Errors
>
> All MPI routines (except MPI_Wtime and MPI_Wtick) return an error value;
>
> ...
>
> MPI_ERR_COMM
>
> Invalid communicator. A common error is to use a null communicator in a call (not even allowed in MPI_Comm_rank).

You thought this call succeeded because you haven't checked the return value,

Comment: Sorry, I had a problem with my test, `MPI_Comm_set_errhandler` gives a fatal error in both libraries, which means that I cannot even set up the error handler in the first place. I was hoping that there was some higher level function that would allow you to introduce a global error handler than can capture this error somehow.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect this change and note some implementation details of MPICH.